# Appending UTM parameters to my current URL

Tags: javascript

I am grabbing the utm parameters from the URL on my index page, and storing them in local storage, then I am using the script below to grab the parameters from local storage and appending them to the end of the contact page's URL.

```
<script>
  var parameters = localStorage.getItem("url");    
  const nextURL = window.location.href + parameters;
  window.history.replaceState(nextURL);
</script>
```

**Problem:** This script works perfectly, except each time I refresh the contact page, it appends the parameters again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse and modify the URL for you. That way you don't have to do any work to produce a valid string:

```js
function buildUrl(fromURL, fromQuery) {
  const url = new URL(fromURL);
  
  const query = new URLSearchParams(fromQuery);
  for (const [key, value] of query) {
    url.searchParams.set(key, value);
  }
  
  return url.toString()
}

function test(fromURL, fromQuery) {
  const url = buildUrl(fromURL, fromQuery);
  return `fromURL: ${fromURL}
fromQuery: ${fromQuery}
result: ${url}
---------------------`;
}

console.log(test("http://example.com", ""));
console.log(test("http://example.com", "foo=1"));
console.log(test("http://example.com", "foo=1&bar=2"));
console.log(test("http://example.com", "foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"));

console.log(test("http://example.com?hello=world", ""));
console.log(test("http://example.com?hello=world", "foo=1"));
console.log(test("http://example.com?hello=world", "foo=1&bar=2"));
console.log(test("http://example.com?hello=world", "foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"));

console.log(test("http://example.com?bar=someValue", ""));
console.log(test("http://example.com?bar=someValue", "foo=1"));
console.log(test("http://example.com?bar=someValue", "foo=1&bar=2"));
console.log(test("http://example.com?bar=someValue", "foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a quick if statement to check if parameters exists in the current URL and if not, add it.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?" + parameters) == -1){
  const nextURL = window.location.href + '?' + parameters;
  window.history.replaceState('', '', nextURL);
}
```